# Imaging Translation returns to origin

Tags: c#, image-processing, windows-phone-8.1

i have an issue which and an internet search provided no help with.
I am trying to translate an image in C# (on WP8.1).

Therefore I used the translate transform(). in the ManipulationDelta event.
it might work, because i can actually move it a few inches but it returns to the origin just after. (even if i keep my finger on the screen)

I got this problem for 3 days now and I am unable to fix it. 
Any help from u guys would be appreciate.

(Code is attached)

```
    void Isetta_ManipulationDelta(object sender, ManipulationDeltaRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        //Actually moving the UI Element

        TranslateTransform tt = new TranslateTransform();
        tt.X += e.Delta.Translation.X;
        tt.Y += e.Delta.Translation.Y;

        Isetta.RenderTransform = tt;

        //Isetta.Height *= e.Delta.Scale;
        //Isetta.Width *= e.Delta.Scale;




    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're creating a new transform each frame and throwing out the old information. You should only create the transform once and reuse it.

You can check if Isetta.RenderTransform is already a TranslateTransform and only replace it if not. Something like:

```
TranslateTransform tt = Isetta.RenderTransform as TranslateTransform;
if (tt == null) 
{
    tt = new TranslateTransform();
    Isetta.RenderTransform = tt;
}
tt.X += e.Delta.Translation.X;
tt.Y += e.Delta.Translation.Y;
```

Or you can just set the transform once, either in Xaml or when initializing the page, and use the same reference. This is what the [Using manipulation events section](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh465387.aspx#using_manipulation_events) in MSDN's [Quickstart: Touch input](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh465387.aspx) does.

Comment: You are the man, thank you so much.
After the solution is provided i feel like a former blind man seeing light for the first time.